# Merge multiple json arrays into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have these arrays:

```js
const characters = [{
  Tom: {},
  Jerry: {}
}]

const data1 = [{
  Species: 'Cat',
  Gender: 'Male'
}]

const data2 = [{
  Species: 'Mouse',
  Gender: 'Male'
}]
```

The final array should look like this:

```js
const characters = [{
  Tom: {
    Species: 'Cat',
    Gender: 'Male'
  },
  Jerry: {
    Species: 'Mouse',
    Gender: 'Male'
  },
  character3: {
    // data3 here
  },
  character4: {
    // data4 here
  }
}]
```

How can I push the data to its position in the main array?

If I have more characters, I will have more data to push, relative to the character.

Comment: what if the data1 is made of more than one element, for instance?

Comment: Those are arrays, not JSON arrays. JSON is a text format. Anyway, all of your arrays only have a single element, which is kind of pointless. There's also no reference of any kind connecting `data1` to `characters[0].Tom`. So it's not clear how this is supposed to work other than hardcoding the relationship, i.e. `characters[0].Tom = data1[0];`, etc

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a JavaScript object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs ([source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order), [source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order#:%7E:text=An%20object%20is%20an%20unordered,can%27t%20guarantee%20the%20order.)). It may work in some cases, but as long as you keep use `characters` as an object and not an array, you will likely end up with some unexpected results.

If you switch your approach to using `characters` as an array instead, this is quite simple to do. here is how I would do it:

```js
const characters = ["Tom", "Jerry"];

const data1 = {
  Species: 'Cat',
  Gender: 'Male'
};

const data2 = {
  Species: 'Mouse',
  Gender: 'Male'
};

const characterAssign = (characters, ...datasets) => Object.fromEntries(characters.slice(0, datasets.length).map((character, i) => [character, datasets[i]]));

const charactersObj = characterAssign(characters, data1, data2);
console.log(charactersObj);
// ➞ {Jerry: {Species: "Mouse", Gender: "Male"}, Tom: {Species: "Cat", Gender: "Male"}}
console.log(charactersObj.Jerry);
// ➞ {Species: "Mouse", Gender: "Male"}
console.log(charactersObj.Tom.Species);
// ➞ "Cat"
```

The first part of our `characterAssign` function `slice(0, datasets.length)` ensures that we only work with as many characters as there are datasets passed into the function for. So if you were to pass in an array of `["Tom", "Jerry", "Spike"]` with only two datasets, "Spike" would be excluded from the returned object since there was no dataset provided for him. This is quality assurance.

Next, we map the datasets passed into the function to each character by index value (`0,1,…`). This creates an array of arrays for each character. Finally, all of that is computed by the `Object.fromEntries` method and converted into an object so characters can be referenced by name in the returned function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all take characters keys out of array or dictionary. Using both is useless.

After that you can loop your characters keys and you can set your data as value.

Code:

```js
    const characters = {Tom: {}, Jerry: {}};
    const multiple_data = [{Species: 'Cat', Gender: 'Male'}, {Species: 'Mouse', Gender: 'Male'}];

    for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(characters).length; i++)
    {
        characters[Object.keys(characters)[i]] = multiple_data[i];
    }

    console.log(characters);
```

Output:

```
    [Jerry: {Species: "Mouse", Gender: "Male"}, Tom: {Species: "Cat", Gender: "Male"}]
```